# How do you print a double quote in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am trying to  escape with double quote -

```
out.print(" \" ");
```

This does not work in JSP.

I have tried printing it out in single quotes

```
out.print(' " ');
```

this does not work either.

*What is the problem? I have been looking for this answer for ever and I feel like the solution is staring me in the face. 
and don't give me the Java solution, you can not escape them like you do in Java, it does not work in JSP for this issue.*

Comment: Have you tried ('\\"')?

Comment: tried `out.print("&quot;")` yet?

Comment: Your first line works for me. The Java solution works because it is Java.

Answer (score 1):

out.print("\"");

This solution ended up being the one that worked. My editor kept telling me that it wasn't valid code, but it ran just fine.

Answer (score -1):

print this instead:

```
out.print("&quot;");
```

Comment: This one didn't work. But escaping them does actually work with JSP, my editor was messing with me, i should've known better